# Displaying PDF in iframe when JS is disabled

Tags: asp.net, firefox, iframe, pdf.js

hi im displaying the pdf using iframe in my application when JS is disabled and when it is enabled im using the PDF.js. The problem is when JS is disabled the iframe is loaded but it shown the html generated similar in the case of pdf.js, and pdf is also not displayed though it is fetched from the server. 
Has anybody else experienced it? how can i display the pdf when js is disabled. It is working fine on other browsers like opera chrome, even on IE :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default pdf viewer used by FF uses javascript so i intalled the adobe plugin and things worked out fine

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
<iframe src='PDFUrl' style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></iframe>
```

I don't think it has anything to do with pdf.js. if file exists, it will be displayed in iFrame.